# How can I use adb shell commands in detox tests?

Tags: javascript, java, adb, detox, e2e

```
`it('TC-30: WIFI', async () => {
    child.exec('adb shell cmd connectivity airplane-mode enable');
    await element(by.label('Violation №1')).tap();
    const errorMessage = 'no connection';
    waitFor(element(by.label(errorMessage))).toBeVisible();
});`
```

I tried to make smth like this but its not working. Child isnt exist.

So how can I use UI settings directly from e2e tests?

Also how can I import images after opening photo library?